# Super Generic Apple Rejection from using private API. How to find the culprit?

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-privateapi

An update to an existing app  (with small changes) just got rejected with the following reason:

> Performance - 2.5.1 Your app uses or references the following
>   non-public API:
>
> Name

It seems like Apple made some changes in how they check private APIs and [more people](https://twitter.com/jakemarsh/status/776205831922528256) are having this issues. Even [a radar was created](https://openradar.appspot.com/28281569). The thing is that this update is important and I am willing to rename some things to get this through, but just with this information it will be impossible. Name is an extremely vague and used thing over the code and I get way too many matches [with the answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405016/ios-app-rejected-non-public-apis). Do you guys have any idea how I can identify this issue ? Is there any tool that we can run ?

Comment: Yikes. I'd reply to Apple and point out the problem with that rejection. An appeal might work.